# Stream Poco Zip Compression to Poco HTTPServerResponse

Tags: zip, poco

I would like to directly compress a directory into a Poco::HTTPServerResponse stream. However, downloading the zip file produced by the following code leads to a corrupt archive. I do know that the below compression approach does work for locally created zip files as I have successfully done that much. What am I missing or is this simply not possible? (Poco v1.6.1)

```
std::string directory = "/tmp/data";
response.setStatusAndReason(HTTPResponse::HTTPStatus::HTTP_OK);
response.setKeepAlive(true);
response.setContentType("application/zip");
response.set("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"data.zip\"");
Poco::Zip::Compress compress(response.send(),false);
compress.addRecursive(directory,
    Poco::Zip::ZipCommon::CompressionMethod::CM_STORE,
    Poco::Zip::ZipCommon::CompressionLevel::CL_MAXIMUM,
    false, "data");
compress.close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the same technique successfully, with only a slight difference:
The compression method and the compression level (CM and CL).

```
compress.addFile( cacheFile, Poco::DateTime(), currentFile.GetName(), Poco::Zip::ZipCommon::CM_DEFLATE, Poco::Zip::ZipCommon::CL_SUPERFAST );
```

A zip file corresponds to the DEFLATE algorithm, so when unzipping, your explorer/archive manager probably doesn't work out.
Either that, or it's pointless to use a MAXIMUM level on a STORE method (STORE non compressing by definition).

EDIT: Just tried it, actually, it's because CM_STORE internally uses headers (probably some kind of tar). Once your files have been added to the zip stream and you close it, Poco tries to order the header, and resets the position of the output stream to the start to write them.
Since it cannont be done on the HTTP output stream (your bytes are already sent!), it fails.

Switching to CM_DEFLATE should fix your problem.